# font = cv2.cv.InitFont(cv2.cv.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, 0.5, 0, 3, 1) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cv'

Tags: python, opencv

Run on the python 2.7, opencv3.4,but it said I didn't attribute.But I think I did. Here is my code
Web said it because I use  OpenCV 3 as it was working fine in below version, but I don't know how to use others

---

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

lowerBound = np.array([33, 80, 40])
upperBound = np.array([102, 255, 255])

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
kernelOpen = np.ones((5, 5))
kernelClose = np.ones((20, 20))

font = cv2.cv.InitFont(cv2.cv.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, 0.5, 0, 3, 1)

while True:
ret, img = cam.read()
img = cv2.resize(img, (340, 220))

# convert BGR to HSV
imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
# create the Mask
mask = cv2.inRange(imgHSV, lowerBound, upperBound)
# morphology
maskOpen = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernelOpen)
maskClose = cv2.morphologyEx(maskOpen, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernelClose)

maskFinal = maskClose
conts, h = cv2.findContours(maskFinal.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

cv2.drawContours(img, conts, -1, (255, 0, 0), 3)
for i in range(len(conts)):
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(conts[i])
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.cv.PutText(cv2.cv.fromarray(img), str(i + 1), (x, y + h), font, (0, 255, 255))
cv2.imshow("maskClose", maskClose)
cv2.imshow("maskOpen", maskOpen)
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("cam", img)
cv2.waitKey(10)
```